# Therapy as Coaching OR Coaching as Therapy

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to write that I'm working as a therapist with a client but using coaching informed approaches.  That is you are entering a legal agreement as a therapist and client and we'll be using Coaching dynamics.

Comment: then it is "coaching as therapy".  the one at the end is the "actual thing".

Comment: Can you think of another example to help me understand better?

Comment: two I came up with, but I'm still not certain:  soup as supper, and breakfast as dinner

Comment: sure, those are perfect examples. soup as supper; corn flakes as dinner.  we're using flour as glue.  we're using hair spray as cleaner.  really it's that simple.  {You can actually use flour as glue, heh!)

Comment: if this simple question is answered please tick it or whatever, so you get points and then you can ask more questions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Then it is "coaching as therapy".

The one at the end is the "actual thing".  It's that simple.

As in your own examples: we're having soup as breakfast; we're using corn flakes as dinner; we're using flour as glue. we're using hair spray as cleaner.  Easy!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer but wanted to provide a source and some more examples.

As the [Cambridge American English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/as) mentions, this construction is a prepositional phrase, where the "as" means "appearing to be, or being."

More examples from source I linked above:

> He went to the costume party dressed as a banana.
>   As a child, Miriam had lived in India.
>   The news came as no surprise.

In this case, you are using coaching techniques that actually are therapy. Therefore, "Coaching as therapy" is the correct order.